# How can I monitor DVR Cameras?

Tags: 10.04, camera

I have a DVR installed and works great... I have the IP address and when I write it in IE9 works perfect (via web service)... How can I monitor them via web?

I tried with every Browser at Ubuntu Software Center and I can't see them =(... (I can enter to the DVR, but the interface is just a shame)

Comment: Screens please :D

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/2nb6noy/5 This is how I see my DVR in Chromium. And this is what happens when I try to open my DVR Client with wine http://tinypic.com/r/2jdp34n/5

Comment: Hmm.... Maybe come to the chatroom in a few hours, some of them may be able to help :D

Comment: What's the server time?. Thanks!

Comment: Its in UTC, now its 12:55

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Meye or Vmeyesuper is possible to run as a google chrome extension. In order to do this you need to install the Google chrome, the Archon extension for the browser and chromeos-apk. Then you need to download the apk and with chromeos-apk convert it to a google chrome extension by: chromeos-apk vmeyesuper.apk --archon. Then you need to load Archon and the converted apk as unpacked extension to google chrome.

With current release of chromeos-apk you will need to add "message": "VM", to the extname section of the messages.json file like this:

```
{
  "appNotSupported": {
    "description": "Message displayed when the app is not supported.",
    "message": "This app is incompatible with your device. Check to make sure other Android apps work for you from the Chrome Web Store"
  },
  "extName": {
    "message": "VMeyesuper",
    "description": "Extension name"
  }
}
```

In case of Ubuntu then you can search in dash for VMeyesuper or whatever name you gave to the application in extname section.

[image: VMeyeSuper on Ubuntu][image: VMeyesuper about] [image: VMeyesuper settings]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**VLC**](http://www.videolan.org/doc/), it has *Linux, Windows, Android,...* versions.

Install it on Ubuntu with

```
sudo apt install vlc*
```

This ensures that you also install all plugins.

Open VLC and in the menu **media** click on **Open Network Stream**, or use the shortcut <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>**+**<kbd>**n**</kbd>.

Now you can input your streaming address and configurations, e.g.:

```
rtsp://192.168.1.55:554/user=USER&password=PWD&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?real_stream--rtp-caching=100
```

Further documentation can be found on the VLC web page or using

```
man vlc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install Play on Linux (POL), then install the IE6 only.

After installation in the settings install the vcrun6 libraries (this includes mfc42.dll as well).

Then run your OCX setup software supplied with your DVR in the POL settings Miscellaneous pane - run exe file in this virtual drive and install the OCX.

After successful setup of OCX run the Internet Explorer, type in your DVR address and log in. You should be able to see the cameras after login.

IE7 or IE8 in Play on linux are not doing so well in terms of compatibility with wine and combined with DVR ocx. You can try it, whether it works with your DVR. If the IE crashes, you may try different version of the DVR OCX software, which worked for me at least.

You can install it also via automatic script in POL: WEB Surveillance DVR OCX with Internet Explorer 6:  https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-2604-WEB_Surveillance_DVR_OCX_with_Internet_Explorer_6.html

Answer (score 1):

If your DVR supports rtsp, you can monitor multiple channels via vlc plugin in firefox.

Create a blank html file with following content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Net Surveilance</title>
<body>
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
       width="550"
       height="400"
       id="vlc" />

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var vlc = document.getElementById("vlc");
var options = new Array(":aspect-ratio=4:3", ":rtsp-tcp");
var id = vlc.playlist.add("rtsp://192.168.1.55:554/user=USER&password=PWD&channel=1&stream=1.sdp?real_stream--rtp-caching=100", "fancy name", options);
vlc.playlist.play();
//-->
</script>

<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
       width="550"
       height="400"
       id="vlc2" />

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var vlc2 = document.getElementById("vlc2");
var options = new Array(":aspect-ratio=4:3", ":rtsp-tcp");
var id = vlc2.playlist.add("rtsp://192.168.1.55:554/user=USER&password=PWD&channel=2&stream=1.sdp?real_stream--rtp-caching=100", "fancy name", options);
vlc2.playlist.play();
//-->
</script>

<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
       width="550"
       height="400"
       id="vlc3" />

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var vlc3 = document.getElementById("vlc3");
var options = new Array(":aspect-ratio=4:3", ":rtsp-tcp");
var id = vlc3.playlist.add("rtsp://192.168.1.55:554/user=USER&password=PWD&channel=3&stream=1.sdp?real_stream--rtp-caching=100", "fancy name", options);
vlc3.playlist.play();
//-->
</script>

<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
       width="550"
       height="400"
       id="vlc4" />

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var vlc4 = document.getElementById("vlc4");
var options = new Array(":aspect-ratio=4:3", ":rtsp-tcp");
var id = vlc4.playlist.add("rtsp://192.168.1.55:554/user=USER&password=PWD&channel=4&stream=1.sdp?real_stream--rtp-caching=100", "fancy name", options);
vlc4.playlist.play();
//-->
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Replace the IP address and USER, PWD in the links:

```
rtsp://192.168.1.55:554/user=USER&password=PWD&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?real_stream--rtp-caching=100
```

with your data. You can also amend the rtsp link accordingly to match your DVR.

Tested with vlc firefox plugin on UBUNTU via remote VPN.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the dvr uses a OCX (activex) controller that must be installed and only in iexplorer. It would be nice to have a program like Meye (used on iphone, bberry, android, etc.) maybe is possible using a emulator of these mobile systems, and then load Meye to see the cams on DVR.

Comment: i have found this
[link](http://www2.mtt.cl/testConasetWeb/jsp/Test.jsp?licencia=B)

is in spanish (translate it) but seems work for this.

the idea is to be able to run Android apps on ubuntu. Android is based on linux.

then load Meye for Sndroid.

Comment: ... " android "

Answer (score 0):

AndroVM runs Android in a virtual machine, so you can use mEye (or some of the many variants). I've just installed it on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and it works just like an Android phone or tablet - but, unfortunately, the camera image is not displayed in mEye.

Perhaps this can be solved via configuration tweaks or in the next version of AndroVM.